# How to remove whole DIV, based on text inside of inner SPAN

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

Could you please give an advice - how can I remove/hide whole div block using my Tampermonkey? The code shown below:
how can I remove the whole div "relative ember-view" if it contains a span with text ADSWG somewhere deep inside in the parent div "relative ember-view"?
So on the web-page a lot of "relative ember-view"-divs, but I'm trying to remove only these, which contains ADSWG in the span tag.

Hope, I've explained it clearly. Thank you in advance.

```html
<div id="ember175" class="relative ember-view"> 
    <div id="ember177" class="occludable-update ember-view">
        <div .....
        <span class="...
            <div id="ember270" class="
                <span id="ember273" class="ember-view">
                        <span>ADSWG</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referencing jQuery in your TamperMonkey script (which I'm going to assume given the tags on the question), then this is a one-liner using `:has`, `:contains` and `remove()`:

```js
$('div.relative.ember-view:has(span:contains("ADSWG"))').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Content before</p>
<div id="ember175" class="relative ember-view">
  <div id="ember177" class="occludable-update ember-view">
    <div>
      <span class="foo">
        <div id="ember270" class="foo">
          <span id="ember273" class="ember-view">
            <span>ADSWG</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Content after</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following on click using `$.each`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnShow").click(function() {
    debugger
    ShowHideDiv('show');
  });
  
  $("#btnHide").click(function() {
    ShowHideDiv('hide');
  });

  function ShowHideDiv(click) {
    var div = $('div .ember-view').find('span');
    $.each(div, function(i, span) {
      if (span.innerHTML.trim() == 'ADSWG') {
        if (click == 'show') {
          $(div).show();
        } else if (click == 'hide') {
          $(div).hide();
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ember175" class="relative ember-view">
  <div id="ember177" class="occludable-update ember-view">
    <div>
      <span>
        <div id="ember270" >
          <span id="ember273" class="ember-view">
            <span>ADSWG</span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btnShow">SHOW DIV</button>
  <button id="btnHide">HIDE DIV</button>
```